# compactness in finite-dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that if the set  $\{(x,y):\|x\|=\|y\|=1,\|x−y\|\ge\epsilon\}$ is compact,in a finite-dimensional space,then I can deduce that a strictly convex space with finite dimension is also uniformly convex but my problem is to show that the set mentioned is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $X$ denote the finite-dimensional space in question and 
$$ K := \{(x,y) \mid \|x\| = \|y\| = 1, \|x-y\| \ge \epsilon\} \subseteq X^2 $$
Now $X^2$ is also finite-dimensional and hence its closed bounded subsets are compact (since $X^2 \cong \mathbb K^n$ for some $n$ and this holds true in $\mathbb K^n$). But $K$ is closed and bounded.

---

Addendum: To see that $K$ is bounded, note that for $(x,y) \in K$ we have
$$ \|(x,y)\|_{X^2} = \|x\| + \|y\| = 2 $$
To see that $K$ is closed, suppose we have $(x_n, y_n) \in K$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y) \in X^2$. Then $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$ and by continuity of $\|\cdot\| \colon X \to \mathbb R$ 
$$ \|x\| = \lim_n \|x_n\| = 1, \quad \|y\| = \lim_n \|y_n\| = 1 $$
and 
$$ \|x-y\| = \lim_n \|x_n - y_n\| \ge \epsilon $$
Hence $(x,y) \in K$.

Comment: But I cant accept that K is bounded and closed.

Comment: See what I added